# Replacement involving Log not working

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

In the following  expression

```
Log[a/6] + Log[b/7]+Log[c/7] + Log[b/8]
```

I want $log(\frac{b}{7})$ and $log(\frac{b}{8})$ to be replaced by $log(b)-log(7)$ and $log(b)-log(8)$. I have tried with this

```
Log[a/6] + Log[b/7] + Log[c/7] + Log[b/8] /. Log[b/x_] -> Log[b] - Log[x]
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Try using `PowerExpand`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at

```
FullForm[Log[b/7]]
(* Log[Times[Rational[1,7],b]] *)
```

and adapt your pattern to

```
Log[a/6] + Log[b/7] + Log[c/7] + Log[b/8] /.
   Log[Rational[1, x_]*b] -> Log[b] - Log[x]
```

Further, note the comment of Carl and be aware of the functions

```
Log[a/6] + Log[b/7] + Log[c/7] + Log[b/8] // FunctionExpand
(* -2 Log[7] - Log[48] + Log[a] + 2 Log[b] + Log[c] *)

Log[a/6] + Log[b/7] + Log[c/7] + Log[b/8] // PowerExpand
(* -4 Log[2] - Log[3] - 2 Log[7] + Log[a] + 2 Log[b] + Log[c] *)
```